# rsync directories that need sudo permissions on the remote server

Tags: rsync, sudo

I have one local server, let's call it as A, which has access to a remote server.

I want to synchronize with `rsync` a directory from the remote server to the local one, and I want to put the synchronized directory in a mounted unit on A.

The problem is that the remote directory has restricted permissions, so I must run the `rsync` command in `sudo` mode on the remote server, but from the server A.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy more simple is to log in the *remoteserver* and from there run the *rsync* command, with sudo privileges.

I assume you are working under Linux on both machines.
Let's we call *localuser* the username on the *localserver*, and *remoteuser* the username on the *remoteserver*.

- On the *localserver* is mounted an external unit in the path `/media/MyUsb`
- On the *remoteserver* there is a directory called `/data/DirToSync`.

```
localuser@localserver ~> ssh -X remoteuser@remoteserver
```

It should ask you the password for the *remoteuser* on the *remoteserver* and
after it will show the prompt on the remote server:

```
remoteuser@remoteserver ->
```

Here you can write the *rsync* command:

```
sudo rsync  -av /data/DirToSync localuser@localserver:/media/MyUsb
```

It will ask before the password for `sudo` on the remote machine (the one of *remoteuser@remoteserver*) and after the password of the destination(the one of localuser@localserver).

**Notes**

1. You need to be in [the sudoers list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#Configuration) of the remote machine (it means you have to have the right to run `sudo`). Try to do `sudo ls` on the remote server and give your password when requested. If it will execute the `ls` command you are in that list. (It should be a really rare and insecure case if you were in that list and with no need of password; in that case you have not to write the password for `sudo`).
2. It will be not asked you the passwords for the `ssh/rsync` connections if  you have generated and installed [the ssh-keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).
3. via `ssh` you can even send the `sudo` command to `rsync` from there to the localhost, but it is a little more complex syntax, see [here for example](https://serverfault.com/questions/625641/how-can-i-run-arbitrarily-complex-command-using-sudo-over-ssh), and you can incur in some problem because of `sudo` on some version of linux.